# I do not understand the break command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, break

in:

```
#!/bin/sh

for var1 in 1 2 3
do
   for var2 in 0 5
   do
      if [ $var1 -eq 2 -a $var2 -eq 0 ]
      then
         break 2
      else
         echo "$var1 $var2"
      fi
   done
done
```

the output is:

```
1 0
1 5
```

and then script stops.

how ever if the break command's argument (2) is removed, the output is:

```
1 0
1 5
3 0
3 5
```

What i am asking is why `3 0` and `3 5` are printed, when the script is conditioned not to break? script didn't print `2 0` and `2 5`, and `3 0` and `3 5` should signal a break as well...

Comment: `break 2` will stop the inner and outer loop. `break 1` aka `break` will only stop the inner loop (the outer loop will then continue on its next iteration). To stop the entire script, use `exit`

Comment: thanks for the comment, but i still dont understand why `3 0` and `3 5` are outputs? both of them should activate the break, just like `2 0` and  `2 5`

Comment: Your condition is `$var1 -eq 2 -a $var2 -eq 0`, and `3 0` is not equal to `2 0`. Did you mean to use `-gt` for "greater than" instead? If you instead wanted to stop the entire script upon reaching `2 0` and not continue with anything, you can use `exit` (or `break 2` to end both loops as you did)

Comment: wow im stupid... yes i meant to and thought i was using gt....  thank you

Comment: Oops :P  This is a pretty good, on-topic question that contains complete source code plus actual and expected output. It's up to you whether you want to accept an answer (click the check mark next to it) or close/delete it due to being "a simple typographical error [...] unlikely to help future readers"

Comment: if `[ $var1 -eq 2 -a $var2 -eq 0 ]` states that `$var1` and `$var2` both must meet the condition for the whole condition to be true. why `2 5` was not an output? ( in the case of using `break 1` )

Comment: `break` aborted the inner loop, so it never kept going to reach `2 5`. You could have used `continue` if you wanted to skip to the next iteration instead (thereby skipping `2 0` and continuing to show `2 5`).

Comment: thank you so much for the answers. i want to check mark your answers but there is not check mark, as a matter of fact, your answers are not within the other 3 answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments, there were two issues:

- Why is `3 0` printed after a `break`, but not after `break 2`?

This was because the condition (`[ $var1 -eq 2 -a $var2 -eq 0 ]`) checked for equality rather than `-ge`, greater or equal. With `-ge` there will be no `echo`s where both numbers are greater.

The `break 2` instead exited both loops, thereby giving the same effect in this particular case. If the loop had been `for var1 in 1 2 0`, `break 2` would have also prevented `0 0` from showing up since both loops would have been stopped.

- Why is `2 5` not printed after a `brake`?

This is because the entire inner loop stops on a `break`, so no other iterations will have their chance to `echo`. To instead skip the current iteration and immediately try the next one, use `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

The optional argument to `break` tells it which loop to break out of. If the argument is omitted, it breaks out of the innermost loop. With an argument `n` it breaks out of the `n`th enclosing loop.

So `break 2` breaks out of the `for var1` loop, because it's the 2nd enclosing loop. If you change it to `break`, it just breaks out of the `for var2` loop, so it goes to the next iteration of `for var1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple `break` breaks out of one loop - the inner for loop in your case.
However, if you use an additional integer in the break statement, as in `break 2`, then breaks out of the specified number of loops - that is *two* for loops in your case. Since there are no more than two nested loops and there is no more code after the outermost loop, it is effectively the same as ending the script.